# Problem in Process Run

Tags: c#

When I want to create a new process that target my files, It seem that I have problem with new threads ?

Where is my problem ?

When I started My Application with Proces.Run :

Error message is : Controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread .

but when I want to start normally , I got no problem .

Comment: Please elaborate your question providing a code example

Comment: Please give a *lot* more detail than this. "It seem that I have problem with new threads" gives us very little information to work on.

Comment: Your first problem it posing a question that is answerable.

Comment: We'd have more chance of guessing a number someone was think of.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Can you show us your code? There is no `Run` method in the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class, only a `Start`method. This seems confusing. Maybe you are trying to create a *thread*?  Note that you can create and update GUI controls only from the applications main thread (you can search SO to find an answer how to do that).

Comment: I am using WinForms .

Also When I started a new process with C# , I got problem , otherwise , there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void UpdateLabelText(String value)
{
  if (_Form.InvokeRequired)
  {
    try { _Form.BeginInvoke(new StringParameterDelegate(UpdateLabelText), new object[] { value }); }
    catch { ;}
    return;
  }

  foreach (Control ctrl in _Form.Controls.Find("labelName", true))
  {
    ((Label)ctrl).Text = value;
    break; // Controls have unique names
  }
}

delegate void StringParameterDelegate(string value);
```